# Блоки не встают в ряд

Tags: css

Нужно разместить блоки `div` в ряд. [Мой код](http://jsfiddle.net/4xw3Leyn/):

```
<div class="alert alert-info" style="width: 100%">
  <div style="float:left; width: 48%">
    <center>Вы </center>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 4%">
    <div style="width: 1px; height: 100px; background-color: #97070B;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right; width: 48%">
    <center>Вы </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что в центре должен быть `div` типа вертикального `hr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, как-то так с использованием HTML и CSS.

[Фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/4xw3Leyn/2/)

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 48%;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 48%;
  background: #777
}
.hr {
  float: left;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #97070B;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-info" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="left">Вы 1</div>
  <div class="hr"></div>
  <div class="right">Вы 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`div` - блочный элемент: элементы, после него, будут помещены на новую строку. [Используйте](http://jsfiddle.net/4xw3Leyn/23/) [`display: inline-block;`](https://webref.ru/css/display):

```css
div.left {
  float:left;
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.right {
  float:right;
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.separator {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #97070B 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <center>
    Вы 1
  </center>
</div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="right">
  <center>
    Вы 2
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Не помогает.

Comment: И правда. =)